# fern-wifi-cracker not working after latest Kali Linux update

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, python3

Yesterday I tried to run fern, it asked for the latest python update so I updated Python 2.7 to Python 3.8 and then I also updated Kali since then fern is not opening. I tried uninstalling fern, I tried updating fern. I tried opening it through terminal but I gave my python not found error. What should I do?

Comment: Please add the exact command you typed at the command line to try to launch fern. Also copy and paste the exact error.  Please [edit] these into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with the package: https://github.com/savio-code/fern-wifi-cracker/issues/132

According to this it appears that fern is not automatically selecting python 3 correctly.  Apparently you can run it by calling

```
python3 <path to fern>
```

Comment: edit the script in `/usr/bin/fern-wifi-cracker` and change it there.

Comment: @Adeerlike that will of coruse work but if a new version is released the next apt update will blow away your changes.

Comment: Right, my point was you need to have the path to actual fern binary, which is not in /usr/bin.